# Get the scroll distance from bottom to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div container. It has a scrollbar. I want to get the distance between the scroll and the bottom

[image]

Tried this without any luck.

```
var posTop = $('.container').scrollTop() - $('.container').offset().top;
```

What is the correct way to get that distance height ?

Comment: Do you mean distance of the scrollbar to the bottom of the scroll handle, or distance from the bottom of the screen to the bottom of the available content?

Comment: Good question, I am asking both...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To calculate the height of the remaining document you can subtract the position of the bottom of the element from the maximum scroll height. Try this:

```js
$('#container').scroll(function() {
    var remaining = $(this).prop('scrollHeight') - ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height());
    $('#debug').text(remaining);
}).scroll();
```

```css
#container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: #CCC;
    position: relative;
}
#content {
    height: 1000px;
}
#debug {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="debug"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The value can be negative if there is a horizontal scrollbar (which height is included in `$(this).height()`)

Answer (score 4):

We can calculate with those values,

```
var scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset; // current position
var windowSize     = window.innerHeight; // window height
var bodyHeight     = document.body.offsetHeight; // body height
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in my case.

You can try like this

```
var distanceFromBottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(document).scrollTop();
```

Comment: $(window).height() -> isnt this getting the window height instead of the div ?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will be helpful to you .

```
$('#div1').scrollTop($('#div1')[0].scrollHeight);
```